# mySQL Driver class is not being recognised in my Servlet program even after importing the mysql JDBC Connector(driver) API

Tags: servlets, jdbc

I am new to J2EE and I am trying to develop a small application using servlet API. I just have to get same details from the mysql database and to display it on the browser. In my project, i have imported the JDBC API (as i have done for the servlet api, build-path->Configure External Archive). But if i try to execute the war file of that project i am getting the following error (I am not getting any syntax error).

I am getting the error as shown below

> Jun 26, 2018 10:57:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
>   SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [checkingCredential] in context with path [/StudentsApp] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1308)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1136)
>       at com.konman01.studentApp.servlet.CheckCredential.doPost(CheckCredential.java:52)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;

/*
 * Authentication of the login user
 * The user input will be checked with the database username and password information           
 * If the correct username and password is provided, then the profile 
 * containing the user details will be displayed else the login html       page
 *  will be provided  
*/
public class CheckCredential extends HttpServlet{
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    ResultSet res = null;
    String oldPassword = null;

    String regNum = req.getParameter("regNo");
    String password = req.getParameter("password");
    int regNum_int = Integer.parseInt(regNum);

    /*
     * JDBC code starts here
     */
    try{
        /*
         * 1. Load the Driver
         */

        java.sql.Driver drivRef = new Driver();
        DriverManager.registerDriver(drivRef);

        /*
         * 2. Get the Connection via Driver
         */
        String dBurl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jdbc_db?useSSL=false";
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(dBurl, "root", "root");

        /*
         * Issue SQL query via connection
         */

        String query = " select password from students_info "+
                        " where reg_no = ? ";

        pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
        pstmt.setInt(1, regNum_int);
        res = pstmt.executeQuery();

        if(res.next())
        {
            oldPassword = res.getString("password");
        }
        else
        {
            String htmlres = "<html>"+
                                "<body>"+
                                    "<p>There is no records in the database for the given register number</p>"+
                                 "</body>"+
                             "</html>";

            resp.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
            out.print(htmlres);

            if (con != null)
            {
                try {
                    con.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if(pstmt != null)
            {
                try {
                    pstmt.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if(res!=null){
                try {
                    res.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return;
        }       
}
catch(SQLException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally{
    if (con != null)
    {
        try {
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if(pstmt != null)
    {
        try {
            pstmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if(res!=null){
        try {
            res.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }

     }

    }
   }
```

I have tried to execute some sample code only using the servlet and JDBC API, it worked fine. Please help me this.

The following image will show how the API is imported to the project:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is what is causing your error:

```
java.sql.Driver drivRef = new Driver();
DriverManager.registerDriver(drivRef);
```

You don't need to instantiate this class. You can simply call it like this:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

Also, if that doesn't work, try moving the .jar file database connector to the lib folder inside WEB-INF